# Android - Should I use View or not - I want to draw rectangle and drag them around

Tags: java, android, view

I don't know if this should be a question at all, that is, if one must implement a view before drawing anything, then clearly this question is a non-issue but sadly, I'm not at somewhere where I can dismiss this question easily out of hand.

So this is what I want to do: draw a rectangle, and then drag it around on the screen with fingers.

So far there are tutorials which told me that I should use canvas instead of view because it is faster, and imposing multiple views, making them "stack" together could be quite problematic.

But here's a catch, I also stumbled upon this tutorial which kind of suggests that [canvas IS a view and I can't use canvas without view](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/graphics/canvas-graphics/android-canvas-example/) and it also makes tremendous amount of sense becuase virtually everything visible to users in android is a view, a button, a picture, etc. etc.

Now I am confused, can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: you can use `new Canvas(Bitmap)` - so no `View` needed - but i really doubt this is what you want when you need to drag your rectangle

Comment: @pskink In other words, If I want to drag something, I need a view? Then view shall not be substituted or discarded, apparently.

Comment: yes, you need a custom `View` with overriden `onDraw` method

Comment: @pskink OK, so I hope you don't mind me asking a followup question: If I put a button on top of this custom canvas view, it is going to be extremely problematic? For example, the button does not respond at all, because the system decided that It is canvas that's being touched, not the button?

Comment: then you have to extend `ViewGroup`, not `View`

Comment: @pskink thanks, I'll check it out